# Testification on the rabbinic law if the witness is interested

Tags: halacha, edim-witnesses

What is if the witness is interested in the case in which he is called to testify?

Can it be a reason to consider his testament much weaker (or even ignore it)? As I know, in the Torah is mainly the number of the witnesses are prescribed. What is the case with their interests, affecting their beliavibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rambam in [Mishneh Torah Hilchos Eidus 9 (1)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172777/jewish/Edut-Chapter-9.htm) gives

> ten categories of disqualifications. Any person belonging to one of
>   them is not acceptable as a witness.

The tenth one is

> people who have a vested interest in the matter

So we see that someone with a vested interest in the outcome of the case is disqualified as a witness.